# Whats wrong with this $all and $regex MongoDB query

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I Think I've got some weird situation here. 
Hmm, dunno if I can't do something like these below.

The 1st Query without regex

```
db.Books.find(
{attributes: { $all: [ 
{'value_string':'bwOBtHQx','ref':ObjectId("5199ec31d005602b8b000000")},
{'value_string':'ikigzuy','ref':ObjectId("5211d045d005609a65000000")},
{'value_boolean':true,'ref':ObjectId("5199ec7bd005602c8b000002")} ] }
}).explain()
```

This query resulting one record exactly.

The 2nd Query with regex on value_string field.

```
db.Books.find(
{attributes: { $all: [ 
{'value_string':'bwOBtHQx','ref':ObjectId("5199ec31d005602b8b000000")},
{'value_string':/iki.*/,'ref':ObjectId("5211d045d005609a65000000")},
{'value_boolean':true,'ref':ObjectId("5199ec7bd005602c8b000002")} ] }
}).explain()
```

This query doesn't fetch anything. I think it should show the same result as the first one

Example of a Books record.

```
{"id":ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
 "attributes" : [ 
                 { "value_string" : "bwOBtHQx",
                   "ref" : ObjectId( "5199ec31d005602b8b000000" ) }, 
                 { "value_string" : "ikigzuy",
                   "ref" : ObjectId( "5211d045d005609a65000000" ) }, 
                 { "value_boolean" : true,
                   "ref" : ObjectId( "5199ec7bd005602c8b000002" ) } ]
}
```

nb:

1. The "attributes" field is already indexed.
2. "attributes" is an Embedded Document(s) in Many relationship.
3. It works when I use $in operator, but not exactly match the elements I'm looking for.

Is there any alternative?

Comment: `'/iki.*/'` isn't a regex, it is actually a string, you wanna take out the quote literals, in PHP you wanna use `MongoRegex`

Comment: Sorry for that, edited.

Comment: Hmm after a bit of searching I have come to the conclusion (without having a MongoDB to double check this) that $all with not evaluate data types such as regex nested within its query object. You could use `$and` for this instead

Comment: @Sammaye tried that but not working either. `db.Customer.find({ $and: [ {'attributes':{'value_string':'bwOBtHQx','ref':ObjectId("5199ec31d005602b8b000000")}},{'attributes':{'value_string':/iki.*/,'ref':ObjectId("5211d045d005609a65000000")}},{'attributes':{'value_boolean':true,'ref':ObjectId("5199ec7bd005602c8b000002")}} ] }).explain()`

Comment: Yes that will not work, you are using object matching there, you need to combine that with `$elemMatch` (I think that's what it will take, you might be able to just use the positional operator, not sure if it matters to you)

Comment: I'm actually avoiding to use $elemMatch so I still can use the Index, hmm so then I should not use regex for this case, thx btw :)

Comment: Yes exactly however, elemmatch should be able to to use an index